# keyup event applying just last word

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm new to jQuery and Ajax

And I tried to make code that searching only last word

```
<form action="/index/output" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text_box" id="target">   
</form>

<script>
    $('#t').keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/index/output',
            data : {
                text_box : $('input:text').val()
            },
            success : function(html) {
                $('#result').html(html);
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

Now when users type something, it show the results at `<div id="result">`
but I want to submit the data of last word

**For example**

When users type this sentence in textbox

```
He is a handsome guy
```

I want to make transmit only "`guy`"(typed last) through keyup() event

Is it possible to make it using jQuery..? I can't get the hang of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'He is a handsome guy';
var word = str.split(" ").pop();
alert(word);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj2wrdju/)

You can get the value of the input then split that value getting the last word like above

[FIDDLE WITH INPUT](http://jsfiddle.net/sj2wrdju/1/)

Its ok to do the keyup event but i suggest you do it on an `event click` or `event change`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but How can I submit it through to ajax?
text_box : $('input:text').val().split("").pop; 
is not working...

Comment: put it to variable then use that variable as `data:{text_box : word},`

Comment: Thank you Can I ask one more question? 
According to w3c school doc, `pop();` is removing "last elements" but this code "get last word" how could it be possible?

Comment: `var word = str.split(" ").pop();` means that you remove the last word(lets say last word ok?) then what pop() does is return that value (the last word) and put it into the `var word` that is why we will get the last word from that line. I just hope you understand my explanation please dont hesitate to ask id you dont i will try my best to explain it again